# Analyzing latency from systrace tool

Tags: android, analysis, systrace

Below attached image of systrace analysis of application (dialer) of mobile phone. Is it possible to measure latency of dialer or any other apps from this tool. i.e. I want to measure time taken by device to execute and completely opening of dialer?

One can get systrace analysis with below command and device should be connected in debugging mode and should open dialer after writing commands to terminal.

```
$ cd android-sdk/platform-tools/systrace
$ python systrace.py --time=10 -o mynewtrace.html sched gfx view wm
```

then open mynewtrace.html file with browse.

Sorry I cannot upload image due to lack of reputation.

Comment: If you give us a link to the picture, someone with higher reputation can edit it into your question.

Comment: It is text file saved as .html so i cant attach it and saved in my PC, But the command given above will give same thing.

Answer (score 0):

below is the flow and each part can be checked through systrace

touch event -> startactivity -> pause ->activityPause->create Process->attach application(bind application) -> oncreate & onresume -> inflate -> creation finish -> actvitiy Idle